# Как воcпроизводить звук с сайта, при этом не открывая браузер?

Tags: c#

Допустим есть такой сайт с радио трансляцией (Для примера: http://air.radiorecord.ru:8102/fut_320), как можно из программы воиспроизводить звук с этого сайта, при этом не открывая браузер?

Comment: посмотреть как сайт его воспроизводит? скорее всего запрос на сервер вот и все

Comment: @ThisMan да, все правильно, просто запращиваеться видео, в проге можно просто поставить windows player и вставить ссылку на этот сайт, спасибо за подсказку)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WindowsMediaPlayer wmPlayer = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
```

и далее

```
wmPlayer.URL = @"http://air.radiorecord.ru:8102/fut_320";
```